# Pass calling object inside initializer block

Tags: c#, constructor

I am creating an `IEnumerable<Parent>` which has a collection of `Child` using the `Select()` linq statement. I want to be able to pass Parent to Child inside the initiator block.

```
class Parent
{
    IEnumerable<Child> Children { get; set; }
}
class Child
{
    Parent Parent { get; set; }
}
//This is what i want to do
someList.Select(x => new Parent
    {
        Children = x.childList.Select(c => new Child
            {
                Parent = //How do i get this?
            }
    });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot do it like this, because at the time the children objects are instantiated by `Select` the `Parent` object has not been initialized yet. Essentially, it is a chicken-and-egg problem.

However, you can use a delegate with curly braces, like this:

```
x => {
    var p = new Parent();
    p.Children = x.childList.Select(
        c => new Child { Parent = p }
    );
    return p;
}
```

Comment: Curly braces works. To be honest, part of me is hoping its a Javascript developer that picks this up to maintain it, because God did not create method pointers with this in mind...